# 2013 Workflow Limit Concurrent Workflows

Tags: 2013, workflow-manager

I am looking for a way to keep my Workflow Manager working while there are active 2013 Workflows.  I assume I need to lower the number of concurrently running 2013 Workflows, but I'm open to other suggestions. Can anyone help?

On my Farm, there are long running 2013 Workflows.  There are periods of no use, followed by ~5-20 being started almost simultaneously.  Starting so many Workflows, at once, causes a problem.  The Workflows need information from the same list, they block each other, then they go into a suspended state, and they continue ~5 minutes later.  This pattern repeats until all the Workflows finish.  I can see that the Server, my Workflow Manager is on, is at 100% CPU for a few minutes with ~5 minutes of no activity, while the Workflows are not finished.

I found this command but this appears to be for 2010 Workflows:

```
Set-SPFarmConfig –WorkflowPostponeThreshold 1
```

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Whenever I fire off 5-10 workflows the CPU on the workflow server gets locked out at 100% and then some of the workflows get stuck suspended while others complete. This is the error that gets logged into the workflow: RequestorId: d90971a4-53b9-a7cd-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: Error. Received the following from the server when querying for cheniere config: 0 at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at Sy